# Laravel validation first symbol

Tags: laravel, validation

How I can check in Validator username begin by letter or not?

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => 'required|unique:users',
]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use Regular expression in the Validator,

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => [
        'required',
        'regex:/^[a-zA-Z]{1}/',
        'unique:users',
    ]
]);
```

Try this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own validator rules. Check this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression in laravel.

```
return Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => 'required|unique:users|regex:^[a-zA-Z].*',
]);
```